# Unit outward normals

Tags: vectors

Consider the following region $\Omega_a \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$\Omega_a=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y \ge x^a, x \not= 0 \text{ if }a < 0\}$$

Let $\nu_a$ denote the unit outward normal of $\Omega_a$.

How does one find a unit normal that is pointing outward from the region, perpendicular to the boundary $\partial\Omega_a=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y = x^a, x \not= 0 \text{ if }a < 0\}$?

If $a=0$, then $$\nu_0=\langle 0,-1\rangle.$$ If $a=1$, then $$\nu_1=\left\langle \frac 1{\sqrt{2}},-\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\right\rangle.$$
But if $a=2$, how do I find the outward unit normal $\nu_2$? If one were to visualize this, one would see that the unit outward normals are changing in direction with respect to the $x$-value.

Lastly, can one generalize the method for finding $\nu_2$ to one for finding $\nu_a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

$f(x, y) = y - x^a; \tag{1}$

then the "inside" of $\Omega_a$ is the set

$\{(x, y) \mid y > x^a \} = \{(x, y) \mid f(x, y) > 0 \},  \tag{2}$

the "outside" is the set

$\{(x, y) \mid y < x^a \} = \{(x, y) \mid f(x, y) < 0 \}, \tag{3}$

and the boundary $\partial \Omega_a$ is the curve

$\partial \Omega_a = \{ (x, y) \mid y = x^a \} = \{(x, y) \mid f(x, y) = 0 \}. \tag{4}$

$\nabla f(x, y)$ is then normal to the boundary, and points in the direction of increasing $f(x, y)$; it is

$\nabla f(x, y) = (-ax^{a - 1}, 1); \tag{5}$

we want an outward pointing unit normal; thus we take

$\nu_a(x, y) = \dfrac{-\nabla f(x, y)}{\Vert \nabla f(x, y) \Vert} = \dfrac{(ax^{a - 1}, -1)}{\sqrt{a^2 x^{2(a - 1)} + 1}}. \tag{6}$

It is easy to see that (6) specializes to the cases $\nu_a$, $a = 0, 1$, given by our OP dragon.

Comment: I'm not sure if the inclusion of the $T$ notation is necessary; do we need to find the transpose of $\nabla f(x,y)$? From (6) in your answer I wrote: $$\nu_n = -\frac{\nabla f(x,y)}{\|\nabla f(x,y)\|} = \frac{\langle nx^{n-1},-1 \rangle}{\sqrt{n^2x^{2(n-1)}+1}}.$$

Comment: I'm not really sure it's necessary either; indeed, I almost left it out!  It's just that more and more I find myself liking column vector notation; it's so compatible with linear transformations.  In this application, however, I think either row are column vectors are equally adequate.

Comment: As far as the solution working for $n < 0$, can't see any reason it shouldn't as long as we stay away from $x = 0$ . . . .

Comment: In that case, it seems that this solution works not only for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ but also for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. May I have your permission to change the notation from $n$'s to $a$'s accordingly in your answer? (I have already changed the notation for my question.)

Comment: Let me take care of it;  gimme a minute, if you please . . . editing . . . Cheers!

Comment: There, how's that?  I also got rid of those "$T$"s!

Comment: Perfect! Well, almost actually. There are three more $n$'s I still see at the bottom of your answer.

Comment: There!  Now how's that?  And a pleasure working with you!

Comment: Oh drat, the $\Omega$s!

Comment: ***NOW*** I think I got 'em all!